# react native flex question: how to stretch the wrapped item?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox, native-base

i want to achieve the following:

[image]

i am using a module called `react-native-easy-grid`
the whole thing is wrapped inside a `Grid`
with:
*blue line* being `Col`
*red line* being `Row`
*orange line* being `View`

here's my code so far:

```js
<Grid>
      <Col>
        <Thumbnail circular source={selectedChildAvatar} />
      </Col>
      <Col size={4}>
        <Row style={{ flexWrap: 'wrap', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-evenly' }}>
          {/* name, in review */}
          <View>
            {!_.isEmpty(selectedChild) && <Text>{selectedChild.firstName}</Text>}
            <View
              style={{
                flexDirection: 'row',
                alignItems: 'center'
              }}>
              <Text note>In review: {inReviewCount <= 0 && 0}</Text>
              {inReviewCount > 0 && (
                <View
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: 'red',
                    paddingLeft: 4,
                    paddingRight: 4,
                    borderRadius: 50
                  }}>
                  <Text note>10</Text>
                </View>
              )}
            </View>
          </View>

          {/* earnings, penalties */}
          <View>
            {/* earnings */}
            <View
              style={{
                flexDirection: 'row',
                alignItems: 'center'
              }}>
              <ProgressiveImage
                resizeMode='cover'
                imageStyle={styles.badge}
                style={styles.badge}
                source={images.icon.earnings}
              />
              <Text style={[styles.digits, styles.earningDigits]}>12</Text>
            </View>

            {/* penalties */}
            <View
              style={{
                flexDirection: 'row',
                alignItems: 'center'
              }}>
              <ProgressiveImage
                resizeMode='cover'
                imageStyle={styles.badge}
                style={styles.badge}
                source={images.icon.penalties}
              />
              <Text style={[styles.digits, styles.penaltyDigits]}>12</Text>
            </View>
          </View>

          {/* review button */}
          <View style={{ marginVertical: 10 }}>
            <Button
              small
              iconRight
              primary
              block
              disabled={inReviewCount === 0}>
              <Text>Review</Text>
              <Icon name='arrow-forward' />
            </Button>
          </View>
        </Row>
      </Col>
    </Grid>
```

but this is what im getting:
[image]

what approach would it be to stretch the wrapped button to 100% of the width?

thank you!

Comment: Have you tried a width style on the button, something like `<View style={{ marginVertical: 10, width: '100%' }}>`?

Comment: Have you tried a flex style on the button ? `<View style={{ flex: 1}}>`

Answer (score 1):

use flex or set width to 100%

```
<View style={{ marginVertical: 10, flex: 1 }}>
  <Button
    small
    iconRight
    primary
    block
    disabled={inReviewCount === 0}>
    <Text>Review</Text>
    <Icon name='arrow-forward' />
  </Button>
</View>
```